# How can I spawn a process and redirect its stdin and stdout?

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a very tiny http server in c and I'm new to c programming in linux.
I would like to implement a very basic CGI so what I wanto to do is to fork my server process and then execve() the cgi script, I know how to do that but what I want is to pass to the child process the urlencoded POST data over stdin and retrieve the stdout content of the process to send it to the browser.
I know this has something to do with pipe() and dup() or similar but I can't figure it out while reading the source code of a http server on github:

[here is the c source](https://github.com/wlangstroth/thttpd/blob/master/libhttpd.c#L3330) cgi_child function on line 3330

Thank you.

Comment: RTFM, man. Section 2, in particular.

Comment: Look up [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) and [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html).  There are also a lot of related questions on SO - search for an answer.  Also learn about MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Line 3330 is not part of an MCVE.